# Mapping list as jetpack compose remember state - architecture point of view

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building form screen using Android Jetpack Compose. I have sealed class, which is containing this example classes:

```
  data class Description(
    val string: String? = null,
  ) : FormItemType()

  data class Comment(
    val string: String? = null,
  ) : FormItemType()
```

Then I'm building form using list like this:

```
availableFormItems = listOf(
  FormItemType.Comment(),
  FormItemType.Description(),
)
```

And I wanted to build compose screen mapping this elements and then displaying correct jetpack compose component:

```
  val states = screenType.availableFormItems.map {
    remember {
      mutableStateOf(it)
    }
  }

Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
    states.forEach {
      when (it.value) {
        is FormItemType.Comment -> {
          val commentState = (it as MutableState<FormItemType.Comment>)
          CommentView(commentState.value.string)
          [...]}
```

I checked and there aren't unnecessary recomposition. But my question is - is this approach correct from architecture point of view?

Comment: Seems ok. You can also create the mutable state inside of the for loop, that way you won't need the typecast.